# I have a cut on rear tire which I observed after my night ride last night. Tire is maintaining pressure no leaks. Can I do 400km BRM with this tire?

Tags: road-bike

Cut on rear tire, maintaining pressure, no leaks. Is it safe to do 400km BRM with this tire ?

Comment: Can you provide photographs? It really depends on what the cut looks like.

Comment: Look at whether the carcass (= the fabric) inside the tire is cut or not (= can you see cut off threads on the sides of the cut?). If it's cut, failure may be imminent (depending on the length of the cut), if the carcass is undamaged, you can still ride. Be aware though, that long cuts can allow small stones to cause a flat that would otherwise not be able to puncture the tire.

Comment: If you're getting ready for a 400 km, ask yourself how confident you want to be in your equipment at the 200 km point. Is the price of a new rear tire worth more or less than that confidence to you?

Comment: My view, a tyre is a consumable.  If you've got any doubt about the life of the consumable, why not just replace it.  If concerned about the wastage maybe just put the cut tyre aside for emergencies.

Comment: @Hursey All tyres - and tires, too - are definitely consumables.  ;-)

Comment: It’s Vittoria Rubino Graphene 2.0, I’m more confident in this tire as I have been using it since March 2023 and have rode ~1800kms without a puncture. Tire is holding good, inside casing is not visible. Can I use sealant to just cover this cut superficially? Shall I swap the front tire with rear tire ? I don’t have an option of buying a new tire as I have to ride 400km Brevet tomorrow and I can’t get the new tire before 10 days. Now suggest me what is the best possible thing to do at this moment ?

Comment: The absolute last thing I would do is swap this potentially compromised tire to the front.  Catastrophic blow out on the front, you eat asphalt while a catastrophic blow out on the back more often than not you can ride out.  Honestly, just replace it.

Comment: If it is a superficial cut and you have no other options anyway, don't let it ruin your ride. I think, the Rubino are the ones with the checkered side pattern and more of a bulletproof allrounder, I had these on my bike. So, if it is just a superficial cut, no internals are showing and it doesn't extend, it's probably nothing you need to worry about too much right away. Indeed, if you hit the wrong piece of gravel, it might punch through easily but for road riding, give it a try. Or post a pic for better judgement...

Comment: So, how did it go?

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe**   Safety is relative - you might get away with hundreds of rides on this damaged tyre, or you might find it failed before you even start your next ride.

If you're trying to get as much life out of the remaining tread, then buy a spare tyre and carry it with you.  A folding tyre is much smaller than a steel-bead tyre and can be strapped to your downtube for the tour.

The risk is if the cut area doesn't support the tube, and you get a sudden blow-out.   If you can see any tube through the cut, then it WILL herniate out and fail because unsupported tubes cannot hold full pressure without a tyre.

Imagine a surprise blowout on a downhill, or in traffic, or while turning.  This is to be avoided, and if simply fitting a good tyre removes that risk, just do it now.

Answer (score 2):

If the cut is only through rubber and hasn’t damaged the underlying fabric threads (carcass) you are most likely fine. The only caveat is that it can make punctures or future damage in that area a bit more likely.

If threads are damaged or even cut through it’s a different story. A small cut (like 3mm in length, e.g. from puncturing with a small glass shard) is probably still fine. Bulging of the tyre under pressure is always a bad sign. Worst case the tyre can fail catastrophically or it can start to rub on the frame (or on rim brakes) without you noticing.

For cuts in the sidewall you can try to sew them with strong thread (or dental floss) and a strong needle, then cover the threads with elastic glue (e.g. neoprene glue). Putting a tyre boot, a tube patch or some other reinforcement on the inside of the tyre is also commonly recommended.

Comment: I had a good example of this the other day.  A Gator Hardshell had about a 10mm disc of tread completely missing, but the (Kevlar I think) threads were intact and I hadn't even noticed the damage.  I only spotted it when I took the wheel off to change the cassette.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take precautions but risk it.

Assuming you can (or do already) run tubes, if the cut isn't too close to the bead you can get a long way with a boot.  So make sure you have a tyre boot with you, and an extra spare tube.  If you don't have any boots, take some flexible but not stretchy plastic (gel packets, toothpaste tubes etc. are good, as is the sidewall of an old tyre) and some duct tape.  I tape even the commercial boots, which I do carry.  I always have a metre or so of duct tape in my tool kit, wrapped round a pen.

If I'm going to be far from home/bike shops, or riding when they'll be shut, I tend to carry a folding tyre.  And a 400km ride even at BRM pace will mean a lot of riding when everything is shut given the 27 hour limit.  The spare doesn't have to be your first choice - in fact I pick something cheaper and lighter than I normally ride, but with worse puncture protection and worse rolling resistance (I normally run Marathon Supreme 32mm, my spare is a Durano 28).  So if you can get any tyre today that fits your bike, do so, and choose whether to fit it today.

For the future: If I didn't have access to acceptable tyres locally, I'd keep a spare at home.  I do, and anyway I could borrow a lower-spec tyre off another of my bikes.